# Bayes classifier optimality with non probabilistic classifiers

Tags: probability

I understand that [Bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_classifier) is the best classifier we can ever get. It's easy for me to understand how is the unknown probability $P(Y=k|X=x)$ approximated by e.g. independence of features in Naive Bayes or simplifications like Bayes Theorem and Gaussian distribution in LDA or QDA.

But I can't figure out how it corresponds with non-probabilistic classifiers like Classification trees or SVM, which have rather *optimization* character than *probability*. I feel that it is somehow *hidden* inside the classifier, but I can't figure out how are these two approaches related to each other. Or better - how e.g. SVM can be *derived* from Bayes Classifier principle. How can one show about non-probabilistic model that it tries to get the most correct probability estimate of $P(Y=k|X=x)$, implicitly use Bayes classifier and not some other necessarily worse classification rule.

Thank you for an answer